# mysqldump Silently Fails to Backup One Table

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.7, mysqldump

I'm using an application that uses MySQL Server 5.7.16.0 on a Windows Server 2012 R2 server. I cannot update mysql, because the app depends on this version and handles updates of it.

I use mysqldump to backup this database. The database is about 16GB in size.

I have **one** table which does not make it into the backup. mysqldump produces no errors, and the database backups are consistent in every other way I can tell.

Here's the full mysqldump command I'm using to create the backup.

```
mysqldump --user=root -p --host=localhost --protocol=tcp --port=3306 --default-character-set=utf8 --single-transaction=TRUE --routines --events --add-drop-database --complete-insert "DB_NAME" > DB_NAME_datetime.sql
```

That's it. The backup simply doesn't contain one table. This table used to be 4GB, and I've tried truncating it to solve this. The table is empty now, or close to it, and still isn't included in the backup. I'm at a loss with no error messages at all.

Does anyone have any ideas? Happy to provide more information if needed.

Comment: Does your `root` user have privilege to that table? Can you query the table in the mysql client if you connect as that root user? Just because the user is named "root" doesn't guarantee it has all privileges.

Comment: Another suggestion for a test: can you use `mysqldump --no-data` (along with your other options) and does the table appear among the CREATE TABLE statements?

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for that one table.

Comment: Please also post TEXT results of SHOW TABLE STATUS WHERE name LIKE 'missingtbl-name';  for possible clue(s).

Comment: What is the tablename?

Comment: I'm sorry all, I lost access to this database shortly after posting and can't follow up. I do think your questions are great to keep for posterity because I hadn't tried any of them before posting, and they sound potentially promising. Thanks for the comments.